# Backbone model reverts to original state

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to make a simple to do list (with no database--everything goes away on a refresh), and when you click the complete button, the task gets a strike through. That works until you add another task, then the strike through disappears. Any ideas?

```
ToDoList.Views.TaskView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
   this.listenTo(this.model, 'all', this.render);
  },
  tagName: 'li',
  template: _.template($('#task-template').html()),
  render: function() {
   var that = this;
   var renderedHTML = this.template({task: this.model.toJSON()});
   this.$el.html(renderedHTML);
   return this;
  },
  events: {
   'click [data-action="delete"]': 'markAsComplete'
  },
  markAsComplete: function() {
   this.$el.css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
 }
});
```

The template is just a name and a button and that works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show your model and view setup code? My guess is that it is connected to the fact that you are rendering on all events on your model, which is overwriting the `text-decoration` you are applying. A better approach may be to use the `complete` attribute on your model in your template to add a class of 'completed' and style on that. That way you don't need to manually set it in your view, and you can safely re-render whenever needed.

Comment: the answer below worked, but thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks alot like its due to you only using css to do this

```
this.$el.css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
```

If it ever gets re rendered how would the re render know to strike though ?

You need to change an attribute of the task to mark it as complete. and render based on the attribute. Rather than just add CSS randomly

Comment: Thank you! I added a 'complete' attribute and toggle function that renders the strike through.